# How to create an object within involve db in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know that I can use the db schema to easily generate CRUD for me. But I want to do a simple login page, it only using the "user" object, check whether the password & user name is correct. So, I want to create an "system" object which have a "login" method. How can I do that in RoR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Controller and views without model and that will work. It looks like you want a super simple login which is described in [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/21-super-simple-authentication). To see how to restrict access to pages, see the [previous railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/20-restricting-access)

Comment: Um... ..How can I do restriction on my application? I do restriction in the models before. But my system only have the controllers and view, where can I add the restrictions?

Comment: You can do restrictions on controller by via `before_filter`.

Comment: I have updated the answer on how to add restrictions to other controllers.